# Declaring rows in table view: "Expected ';' after method prototype"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'm having some problems with a couple lines of code that are causing my iPhone app to not build. It's part of a lesson in BNR's new "Objective-C Programming" book. Since it just came out on Kindle (isn't even in print yet), there's no addendums or corrections yet.

I'm guessing I have some syntax wrong — if there's any more code before or after I need to add let me know.

Thanks!

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
    // Because this table view only has one section, 
    // the number of rows in it is equal to the number 
    // of items in our tasks array 
    return [tasks count]; 
}
```

**edit: people are asking for some more code so I'm going to add it to pastebin -- I don't want to spam the page here. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/UeeTcpCJ) the header file, [here's](http://pastebin.com/y7skh8G9) the method file.**

Comment: Some other code is causing that error. This code is valid obj-c. Post some more code around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableView dataSource methods needs to be in the `@implementation` block (.m file), not `@interface` (.h file).  Just cut the code from .h and move it to .m file and it should be fine.

Comment: Realized the same answer showed up a couple times, but I needed the clarification between .m/.h files. Thanks! Still learning this stuff and every bit counts.

Comment: This is exactly what my answer said, 47 minutes earlier :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager a guess that you've mixed up your `.h` file and `.m` file.

Make sure you declare headers in the `.h` and implementations in the `.m`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine, so that's not where your problem is. From the error, it sounds like your header file is missing a `;` at the end of a method declaration. Also, make sure the method is being defined inside an `@implementation ClassName … @end` block.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this code is in an `@interface` block, where only declarations can go. It should be in an `@implementation` block.